# How to fetch values from Firestore with where() followed by startAt() and endAt()

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using anguarfire2 and I just need to fetch values from Firestore which is from specific type of customers and order by positions

I have tried the below but not giving me any result

```
angularFirestore.collection('customers', ref => ref.where('type', '==', type)
            .orderBy('position')
            .startAt(1)
            .endAt(2))
```

But

```
   angularFirestore.collection('customers', ref => ref.orderBy('position')
            .startAt(1)
            .endAt(2) )
```

it works. It provides me results regardless of customer type.

Is that possible to fetch values with combination of where, orderBy, startAt and endAt?

Comment: you need to chain multiple where with each clause you want to filter for

Answer (score 0):

You need t paginate the queries as referred in the document here [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query)

You can also refer the code below to achieve the same:

```
let first = db.collection('cities')
           .orderBy('population')
           .limit(3);

let paginate = first.get()
.then((snapshot) => {
// ...

// Get the last document
let last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];

// Construct a new query starting at this document.
// Note: this will not have the desired effect if multiple
// cities have the exact same population value.
let next = db.collection('cities')
  .orderBy('population')
  .startAfter(last.data().population)
  .limit(3);

// Use the query for pagination
// ...
```

});